# Creating a scope without defining a component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `<table>` with a bunch of `<tr>`s and `<td>`s inside. When hovering over a table cell, I want a button to appear inside that cell.

I created a `data` field called `hovered` and added `@mouseenter="hovered = 1"`/`@mouseleave="hovered = 0"` on every `<td>`. Buttons also got `v-show="hovered"`.

As you might guess, whenever I hover over a cell, **all** buttons show up, because they all depend on the same `hovered` value.

I wonder if I really should create my own component `MyTr` to work this around. Is there a way to create some sort of scope right in HTML and not even bother declaring a `data` field?

**UPDATE**

I tried creating a component and faced another problem (besides render bug due to missing `is` [explained here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)). This is my component:

```
Vue.component('td-hoverable', {
  data: function () { return {
      hovered: false
    }
  },
  template: '<td v-on:mouseenter="hovered = 1" v-on:mouseleave="hovered = 0"> <slot></slot> </td>'
});
```

And this is how I use it:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td is="td-hoverable" v-for="..." v-bind:key="di">
   <button v-show="hovered"> x </button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

However, when I launch the app, I get

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "hovered" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

I tried adding `v-bind:hovered="hovered"` to `<slot>`, but that didn't helped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make `hovered` an array instead of a single value, I suppose. But this is a good case for using a component; why do you want to avoid using one?

Comment: @krubo I was hoping to do this with just some HTML tags/attrs. Anyways, I tried component approach and updated my question.

Comment: It looks like the [slot can't directly access the child template variable](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Compilation-Scope). Can you do it without `<slot>`, putting all the td contents inside the td component?

Comment: I can, but this make the component less generic. I find it strange that Vue doesn't allow to do such simple things without hacking it around.

Comment: The idea of components is to keep related parts together in isolated scopes. The idea is that each `<td>` that you hover over, and its respective `<button>` controlled by the hovering would go together inside the component. If you can't put them both inside the component without hacking it around, maybe a component isn't the right choice after all.  It really depends what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is the kind of complexity that calls for a component, but from your trouble with `<slot>` I'm seeing that your use case must be somewhat complex and there may be reasons why you want to avoid making a component for this.

To your original question,  assuming you already have some `id` field to index your table cells, you can make `hovered` a dictionary and index it with the same field. Note that due to [vue reactivity limitations of javascript](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) you can't use `hovered[item.id] = 1` because it won't react, so you have to use `$set(hovered, item.id, 1)`:

```
data: function () { return {
  hovered: {}
}

<td @mouseenter="$set(hovered, item.id, 1)"
    @mouseleave="$set(hovered, item.id, 0)">
  <button v-show="hovered[item.id]">
```

Comment: I've ended up creating a component a putting a button inside it. But all your suggestions were useful.

Answer (score -1):

Should be doable using directives:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html

Comment: Can you, please, expand your answer a bit? Link-only answers are rarely useful.